# How do I grep for lines containing either of two words, but not both?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to use `grep` to show only lines containing either of the two words, if only one of them appears in the line, but not if they are in the same line.

So far I've tried  `grep pattern1 | grep pattern2 | ...` but didn't get the result I expected.

Comment: (1) You talk about “words” and “patterns”.  Which is it?  Ordinary words like “quick”, “brown” and “fox”, or regular expressions like ``[a-z][a-z0-9]\(,7\}\(\.[a-z0-9]\{,3\}\)+``? (2) What if one of the words / patterns appears more than once in a line (and the other one doesn’t appear)?  Is that equivalent to the word appearing once, or does it count as multiple occurrences?

Answer (score 63):

A tool other than `grep` is the way to go.

Using perl, for instance, the command would be:

```
perl -ne 'print if /pattern1/ xor /pattern2/'
```

`perl -ne` runs the command given over each line of stdin, which in this case prints the line if it matches `/pattern1/ xor /pattern2/`, or in other words matches one pattern but not the other (exclusive or).

This works for the pattern in either order, and should have better performance than multiple invocations of `grep`, and is less typing as well.

Or, even shorter, with awk:

```
awk 'xor(/pattern1/,/pattern2/)'
```

or for versions of awk that don't have `xor`:

```
awk '/pattern1/+/pattern2/==1`
```

Comment: Just curious, how could those methods be modified to be word-senstive?  The OP uses the phrase "two words".

Comment: @JimL. You could put word boundaries (`\b`) in the patterns themselves, i.e. `\bword\b`.

Comment: `awk '/pattern1/!=/pattern2/'`

Answer (score 33):

With GNU `grep`, you could pass both words to `grep` and then remove the lines containing both the patterns.

```
$ cat testfile.txt
abc
def
abc def
abc 123 def
1234
5678
1234 def abc
def abc

$ grep -w -e 'abc' -e 'def' testfile.txt | grep -v -e 'abc.*def' -e 'def.*abc'
abc
def
```

Comment: That is cool.  I don't know about if it does both. I did not test, but I did use your answer to do grep on or of two words. `grep -e foo -e goo`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Try with `egrep`

```
egrep  'pattern1|pattern2' file | grep -v -e 'pattern1.*pattern2' -e 'pattern2.*pattern1'
```

Comment: can also be written as `grep -e foo -e bar | grep -v -e 'foo.*bar' -e 'bar.*foo'`

Comment: Also, note from the grep man page: `Direct  invocation  as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated` -- prefer `grep -E`

Comment: I was refering to the text "Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated " (or similar) in the manual page, @terdon. Not in AIX or the BSDs, but is in HP-UX and linuxs

Answer (score 13):

With `grep` implementations that support perl-like regular expressions (like `pcregrep` or GNU or ast-open `grep -P`), you can do it in one `grep` invocation with:

```
grep -P '^(?=.*pat1)(?!.*pat2)|^(?=.*pat2)(?!.*pat1)'
```

That is find the lines that match `pat1` but not `pat2`, or `pat2` but not `pat1`.

`(?=...)` and `(?!...)` are respectively look ahead and negative look ahead operators. So technically, the above looks for the beginning of the subject (`^`) provided it's followed by `.*pat1` and not followed by `.*pat2`, or the same with `pat1` and `pat2` reversed.

That's suboptimal for lines that contain both patterns as they would then be looked for twice. You could instead use more advanced perl operators like:

```
grep -P '^(?=.*pat1|())(?(1)(?=.*pat2)|(?!.*pat2))'
```

`(?(1)yespattern|nopattern)` matches against `yespattern` if the `1`<sup>st</sup> capture group (empty `()` above) matched, and `nopattern` otherwise. If that `()` matches, that means `pat1` didn't match, so we look for `pat2` (positive look ahead), and we look for *not* `pat2` otherwise (negative look ahead).

With `sed`, you could write it:

```
sed -ne '/pat1/{/pat2/!p;d;}' -e '/pat2/p'
```

Answer (score 4):

In Boolean terms, you're looking for A xor B, which can be written as

(A and not B)

or

(B and not A)

Given that your question doesn't mention that you are concerned with the order of the output so long as the matching lines are shown, the Boolean expansion of A xor B is pretty darn simple in grep:

```
$ cat << EOF > foo
> a b
> a
> b
> c a
> c b
> b a
> b c
> EOF
$ grep -w 'a' foo | grep -vw 'b'; grep -w 'b' foo | grep -vw 'a';
a
c a
b
c b
b c
```

Answer (score -2):

For the following example:

```
# Patterns:
#    apple
#    pear

# Example line
line="a_apple_apple_pear_a"
```

This can be done purely with `grep -E`, `uniq`, and `wc`.

```
# Grep for regex pattern, sort as unique, and count the number of lines
result=$(grep -oE 'apple|pear' <<< $line | sort -u | wc -l)
```

If `grep` is compiled with Perl regular expressions then you can match on the last occurrence instead of needing to pipe to `uniq`:

```
# Grep for regex pattern and count the number of lines
result=$(grep -oP '(apple(?!.*apple)|pear(?!.*pear))' <<< $line | wc -l)
```

Output the result:

```
# Only one of the words exists if the result is < 2
((result > 0)) &&
   if (($result < 2)); then
      echo Only one word matched
   else
      echo Both words matched
   fi
```

A one-liner:

```
(($(grep -oP '(apple(?!.*apple)|pear(?!.*pear))' <<< $line | wc -l) == 1)) && echo Only one word matched
```

If you don't want to hard-code the pattern, assembling it with a variable set of elements can be automated with a function.

This can also be done natively in Bash as a function without pipes or additional processes but would be more involved and is probably outside the scope of your question.

Comment: (1) I was wondering when somebody was going to give an answer using Perl regular expressions.  If you focused on that part of your post, and explained how it worked, this could be a good answer. (2) But I’m afraid the rest isn’t so good.  The question says “show only ***lines*** containing either of the two words” (emphasis added).  If the output is supposed to be ***lines**,* then it stands to reason that the input must also be multiple *lines.*  But your approach works ***only*** when looking at only a single line.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  For example, if the input contains the lines `Big apple\n` and `pear-shaped\n`, then the output should contain both of those lines.  Your solution would get a count of 2; the long version would report “Both words matched” (which is an answer to the wrong question) and the short version would say nothing at all.  (3) A suggestion: using `-o` here is a really bad idea, because it hides the lines that contain the matches, so you can’t see when both words appear on the same line.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Bottom line: your use of ``uniq`` / ``sort -u`` and the fancy Perl regular expression to match only the last occurrence on each line don’t really add up to a useful answer to this question.  But, even if they did, it would still be a bad answer because you don’t explain *how* they contribute to answering the question. (See [Stéphane Chazelas’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/497674/80216#497940) for an example of a good explanation.)

Comment: The OP says that they wanted to "show only lines containing either of the two words" which means that each line has to be evaluated on its own. I don't see why you feel that this doesn't answer the question. Please provide an example input that you feel would fail.

Comment: Oh, is ***that*** what you meant?  “Read the input a line at a time and execute these two or three commands ***for every line**.*”? (1) It’s painfully unclear that that’s what you meant. (2) It’s painfully inefficient.  Four answers before yours showed how to handle the ***entire*** file in a few commands (one, two or four), and you want to run 3 × *n* commands for *n* lines of input?  Even if it works, it earns a down vote for unnecessarily expensive execution. (3) At the risk of splitting hairs, it still doesn’t do the job of ***showing*** the appropriate lines.

Comment: That's purely subjective and micro-optimization. I don't know how large the file is and it may be small enough that it doesn't even matter. If some action needs to be performed on each of the resulting lines then the output would be looped over anyways. There is nothing wrong with this answer other than it somehow displeasing you.

Comment: [Why  is  using  a  shell  loop  to  process  text  considered  bad  practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/80216)